# Bottom Space to: UIView Constraint

Tags: ios, uiview, interface-builder, storyboard, autolayout

Boy am I lost with this one. I have two UIViews "TopView" and "BottomView". This is used to have a slide out menu when activated. I have a simply UILabel at the bottom of the page which has a copyright message.

**The Issue:** When viewing the copyright message on different screen sizes it fails. i.e.

- Screen size 4" = Pass
- Screen size 3.5" = Fail (as in you can't see the copyright message)

I have successfully worked out what is causing the issue which is in Xcode adding a constraint to the bottom of UIView sets it to Superview which works perfectly for the 4" but not the 3.5" screen size i.e.

**"Bottom To Space : SuperView"**

What I need to work out is how to change the constraint on the "TopView" to be;

**"Bottom To Space : Bottom Layout Guide"**

Can this be done, if so how? I have a feeling it's breaking the Apple design principles thus it can't be done. I can't believe that is the case as I'm sure I have seen others do it.

Sorry no code as it's all in Xcode Storyboard.

Jeremy

**Update: Attached Images to help provide some context.**

First Image = TopView

Second Image = BottomView

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are lots of ways to solve this, but it depends on what you want to happen when the screen size changes. Do you want either (or both) TopView or BottomView to get smaller when the screen size does? Do you want some space in between these objects or these objects and the superview edges to get smaller?

Comment: Neither. I want the copyright message to slide along with the TopView as the user slides their finger across the UIView. Effectively it's the same as Facebook and countless others in the market.

Comment: I wasn't asking about what happens upon user interaction, I mean how do you want the UI elements to change with different screen sizes? When you go to a smaller screen, either things need to get smaller or closer together or both. Which do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely not against design principles though. You just need to think of this a bit differently. I think the main problem you're having is you are giving the TopView a fixed height constraint. Instead, you need to let the TopView's height be determined by the other constraints it has. Give the bottom view a fixed height, and give the top and bottom view a vertical spacing of zero. Satisfy the other constraints (such as leading and trailing space to superview for both top and bottom view, and the top views top space to superview) and you'll see everything auto layout properly.

Good luck!

Comment: MMm…I sorta understand what you mean…The only thing is both UIViews have no constraints associated to them. In my thinking it makes that screen adjust accordingly depending on if it's 3.5 or 4". When I put a label on the "TopView" along with any other elements i.e. Buttons, textview etc. When you slide the UIView off the stage it take all the elements on that view. If I fix the height would that limit to only one size of screen. I.e. 568 would be 4" etc. Or have I missed your point?….

Comment: I'd suggest adding constraints. The key to getting these to work on both screens is not to set the height on TopView. You want that view's height to be determined at runtime by autolayout. Heres an example: https://github.com/ketzusaka/so-viewalignment

Comment: Okay James, what you said does work for that particular instance. So I'll give you the points for that one. However, what I discovered is that because I'm under NDA with Apple I can't discuss the other reason as it turns out there is more then what I can share on this. Thanks for your help with this one.